# how to run different steps in a yml file depending on the branch trigger

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I make the YAML file to trigger and check out a branch and run diferrent steps?

I am working on a YAML file for azure, and I want run run certain step in my master branch and other steps in a QA branch.

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
steps:
- script: ls $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
  displayName: 'printing the ls
```

I want to check out the master and run a step, but if something change on QA branch I want to trigger, checkout the QA branch and run other steps. What should the YAML look like?

Comment: i saw the extention  .yml    in my explorer

Comment: Then complain to the people that used that extension, or at least mistrust their knowledge: https://yaml.org/faq.html

Comment: that is the file that was generated by Microsoft azure pipeline =)

Comment: @Anthon why so distrustful and judgemental. On windows many files have a long and a 3 letter extension and there is nothing wrong with yml.

Answer (score 5):

On each step you can put a `condition:` to each task/script:

```
 condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')))
```

This will trigger the task for master branch build, except when the build was triggered for pull request validation. A complete example:

```
task: SnykTask@1
  condition: and(succeeded(), and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')))
  displayName: 'Dependency scan'
  inputs:
    file: xxxxx
    test: true
    monitor: false
    authType: endpoint
    endpoint: xxx
    severityThreshold: high
    failBuild: false
```

You can also define a stage in your yaml file. Stages can contain a set of steps and can also be made conditional:

```
stages: 
- stage: string # name of the stage, A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore 
    displayName: string # friendly name to display in the UI 
    dependsOn: string | [ string ] 
    condition: string variables: { string: string } | [ variable | variableReference ] 
    jobs: [ job | templateReference]
```

In the most extreme case you can create multiple yaml files and commit them to source control. Then go into the Azure Pipelines UI and create a pipeline for each yaml file. To make them fully seperate.

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema

Comment: instead having a condition for each step,  can i move the step 2 spaces so they are inside the trigger?

Comment: oh that's nice having 2 files,  is there any particular naming that i should use? or how do i tell witch one will be use?

Comment: whats wrong with conditioning certain steps? why do you want to manage 2 builds\2 files instead of a single build\file

Comment: nothing wrong, i was thinking like python that i could have just have 2 condition,  one for each type of build instead putting the condition on each of the steps.  i have more steps than builds lol =)

Comment: You can also define 2 stages, group all the steps under the stages and put the condition on the whole stage at once.